# How does a javascript && operator work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-proptypes

I want to pass a prop to a React Component, conditional to a boolean in parent component's state, The component expects to have `myProp` as an `object`, the propTypes conflagration is bellow:

```
//component's code
class MyComponent extends Component {

    ...
    static propTypes = {
        myProp: propTypes.object
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, I am on to pass the prop like below:

```
//Parent component's code
class ParentComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          par: true,
        }
    }
    render(){
        const obj = {
            key1: 'value1',
            key2: 'value2'
        }
        ...
        return ( 
            <MyComponent
                myProp = {this.state.par && obj}
            />
        )
    }
...
}
```

Executing the above code it gives me following warning in browser console:

> **Warning**: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `myProp` of type `boolean` supplied to `MyComponent`, expected `object`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case `myProp = {this.state.par && obj}` if this.state.par is false and obj is present then boolean value `false` will be returned instead of `obj`, you should write it like

```
myProp = {this.state.par? obj: null}
```

As per the **[docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)**:

> `true && expression` always evaluates to `expression`, and `false &&
>   expression` always evaluates to `false`.
>
> Therefore, if the condition is true, the element right after && will
>   appear in the output. If it is false, React will ignore and skip it.

Comment: @HaiderAliAnjum Consider accepting the answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

If `this.state.par` is `false`, then `this.state.par && obj` is `false` (boolean, not object).

You may want the conditional operator instead:

```
return ( 
    <MyComponent
        myProp = {this.state.par ? obj : null}
    />
)
```

Now, regardless of the flag, you're providing something of type `object` (`obj` or `null`).

Or somewhat more obscurely, add a `||`:

```
return ( 
    <MyComponent
        myProp = {this.state.par && obj || null}
    />
)
```

...but I'd use the conditional.

---

Of course, `MyComponent` will need to understand that `myProp` may be `null`...

Answer (score 0):

I would include the boolean as a property inside the `obj` and check for the value inside the child component

```
render() {
   const obj = {
        key1: 'value1',
        key2: 'value2'
        par: this.state.par
    }
   return(
       <MyComponent myProp={obj} />
   );
}
```

and handle the true/falsiness in the child component.

Comment: That's not helpful, It actually tends me to implement somecontrlling login in the Component as well. :(

Comment: @HaiderAliAnjum  you don't say whether the rendering of the child component is dependent on the boolean state.  So this solution assumes that you want `MyComponent` to render regardless of state and handle the logic there.